# How to optimize mysql full match

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysql, zend-db-table

Hey guys, do you know some trick about how can I optimize more a full match search?

The code that I'm trying to optimize:

```
$do = $this->select()
      ->where('MATCH(`name`,`ort`) AGAINST( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $theString)
      ->order('premium DESC');
```

The search should search for some companies...and let's say that in the field **name** I have: **Google** and in the **ort** field I have **new york**.

I want to do a query like: **google center in new york** and to give me as a result all the google centers from new york only!

I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: Poorly worded question. What is a full match search? Do you mean a full text search? Perhaps an absolute value match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the relevance to sort

```
$do = $this->select("*, MATCH(`name`,`ort`) AGAINST ('{$theString}') AS score")
      ->where('MATCH(`name`,`ort`) AGAINST( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $theString)
      ->order('premium DESC, score');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at

- [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)
- [Using MySQL Full-text Searching](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

Answer (score 1):

Your type of query might be matched better by a fulltext search in `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` instead of `BOOLEAN MODE`.

If you search for "google center in new york" in boolean mode you'll find any matches of all those keywords, but not necessarily in that order or matching those concepts.